# Step-by-Step/Best way to migrate a NT4 Samba domain to Microsoft AD

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, active-directory, samba

Recently we start having multiple issues with our SAMBA NT4 domain, that is because Microsoft is forcing to stop using it. One of my projects in my current company is to migrate the old SAMBA NT4 domain to a Microsoft Active Directory domain.

My current setup includes 2 Domain Controlers:

**PDC:** "SAMBA1" 
**BDC:** "SAMBA2"
**SAMBA Version:** 4.3..11
**OS:** Ubuntu 14.04
***DOMAIN:*** SCIENCE

I will set-up a lab for testing and eventually moving to production:

- Servers: 2 Windows Server 2016( Primary and Secondary)
- Computers: 2 already in the old domain(these will connect after everything is setup) and 2 other new computers for testing

I would like to know if somebody have a step-by-step guide or the best way to perform the migration.

I am not an expert with SAMBA or AD, but I am learning quick the way they work and everything.

Thank you.